# Sending large file consuming a lot of memory in c#

Tags: c#, streaming

I am sending very large file over TCP/IP network which is working as expected.

Just one concern that how to send it efficiently so that memory consumption should be optimized.

Below is the working code

```
Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(tbFilename.Text);
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
fileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);



// Open a TCP/IP Connection and send the data
   TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(tbServer.Text,8080);
   NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
   networkStream.Write(fileBuffer,0,fileBuffer.GetLength(0));
   networkStream.Close();
```

Comment: You could read the file, while you send it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `Stream.Read` will probably not read the whole file just a chunk, but you omit the return value, which is the number of read bytes.

Secondly, you should use a smaller buffer (eg. 4K) and use that to send the file.

```
const int BUFSIZE = 4096;
long transferred = 0L;
long length = fileStream.Length;
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    while (transferred < length)
    {
        int chunkSize = Math.Min(length - transferred, BUFSIZE);
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(chunkSize);
        networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        transferred += chunkSize;
        // here you can even report some progress to adjust a ProgressBar or something
    }
}
```

Comment: 4K is a little bit little for most scenarios. I would recommend using a buffer of (very roughly) 1M, unless memory is that bad an issue. With smaller buffers, you will notice a negative impact on performance due to repeated disk reads. Going much large with the buffer size again also will not result in a big improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stream.CopyTo() to copy data from a source stream into another.

The CopyTo() method uses a temporary buffer as suggested by taffer.

Do not forget to Flush() the network stream afterwards.

```
    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(tbFilename.Text))
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(tbServer.Text, 8080);
        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        fileStream.CopyTo(networkStream);
        networkStream.Flush();
        networkStream.Close();
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
```

Comment: By the way.. This approach is blocking. (meaning you should execute the code in a background thread otherwise your UI would freeze during the transfer). You can also use fileStream.BeginRead and networkStream.Write in the callback method with a temporary buffer to achieve an asynchronous trasfer.